# Javascript - finding a particular form from a mouse change event

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with 4 separate pulldown option forms and I have an javascript function that gets invoked when any of the forms gets changed via the mouse.

How do I establish which specific forms get changed from the event object and subsequently the particular option change that has been made?

All examples I have seem assume I have a dedicated javascript function for each individual form. But I want to be able to build forms 'on the fly' so I need to pass all forms changes through a  single javascript function.

in answer to the question - here's some more info:

I do use jQuery (but I'm a novice) - the javascript event setup code line is:

```
 document.onchange=this.audioselect
```

and the audioselect function just has a single line at the moment - an  alert which proves the it gets  invoked for each form change:

```
alert("audio Select this: " + evtobj.type.toString(). ).
```

The forms are defined  similar to this one (with each subsequent form name being  incremented:

"

```
    <div id="videoSlot" style="position: absolute; left:250px; top:450.0px; background-     color:green;">
           <img src="http://localhost:9000/HomeVu1/HomeVu1/skin/HomeVu.jpg"
                                width="210.0"
                                height="140.0"
                                           alt="HomeVu1/skin/HomeVu.jpg"
                                           title="HomeVu1/skin/HomeVu.jpg"/>
                                                      <br /> 
    <strong>Select Image 1 Audio
    <form name="audio_form_1" >
      <select name="menu_1" >
                <br />
    <option name = "audio_1" value = "1" >OH Intro </option>

    <option name = "audio_2" value = "2" >OH Front </option>

    <option name = "audio_3" value = "3" >OH Plot </option>

    <option name = "audio_4" value = "4" >OH Hall </option>
</select>   <br /> </form>  </div>"
```

Thanks in anticipation.

-mike

Comment: Can you please post some example code. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input - I've got something working. Firstly, I had to place the script separately from the other set of mouse event functions I have, also the formName is undefined whereas (strangely) the option selectedOption gets set correctly. However, was able to get the form name from the 'this.name' - see the script below:

A bit of a hybrid but is does work.

"

```
$(document).on("change", "form", function(e){

             var currentForm = $(this);
             var formName = currentForm.attr('name');
     var selectedOption = currentForm.find('option:selected').val();

    alert(
        "audio Select Form: " + currentForm.name + " Option: " + selectedOption
            + " this name:" + this.name 
        )

});
</script>"
```

Thanks - mike

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give each of the forms unique ids so that you know which pulldown was clicked and run your dedicated javascript functions accordingly.

Comment: The javascript event setup code is: document.onchange=this.audioselect  and the audioselect function just has an alert in it: alert(
    //"audio Select this: " + evtobj.type.toString()
    "audio Select this: " + evtobj.id.toString()
     )

Comment: <script>

    $(document).on("change", "form", function(e){

        
   var currentForm = $(this);
   var formName = currentForm.attr('form:name');
      var selectedOption = currentForm.find('option:selected').val();
      
    alert(
      "audio Select Form: " + currentForm.name + " Option: " + selectedOption
      + " this name:" + this.name 
     )
     
     });
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is well suited for this task. Attaching events can be a pain across different browsers. Here is a link to a jsFiddle that shows a simple example of how you could achieve something like you are talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/UK2zH/1/

You will need to click the run button at the upper left part of the screen, then make selections from the forms to see alerts of what you selected from where.

In the jsFiddle I am attaching a jQuery event listener to the document - which is important if the forms are going to be created on the fly. The event listener is set to only pay attention to events that happen within form elements.

```
$(document).on("change", "form", function(e){
    var currentForm = $(this);
    var formName = currentForm.attr('name');
    var selectedOption = currentForm.find('option:selected').val();
    alert("form: " + formName + ", selected: " + selectedOption);
});
```

The function that is attached will receive the element that triggered the event as "this". We can then use some more jQuery (by wrapping "this" in a jQuery selector) to get easy access to the form name and selected option, etc.

Comment: <script>

    $(document).on("change", "form", function(e){

        
   var currentForm = $(this);
   var formName = currentForm.attr('form:name');
      var selectedOption = currentForm.find('option:selected').val();
      
    alert(
      "audio Select Form: " + currentForm.name + " Option: " + selectedOption
      + " this name:" + this.name 
     )
     
     });
 </script>